# Append only once Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, html-lists, append

Finally, I have my solution but still a little problem.

I have this list

```
<ul id="tricky_list"> 
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>​
```

I want to show only first 3 (three) elements and show remaining two on mouseover with this function

```
var limit = 3;
var list = $("#tricky_list");
var more = 0;

function tricky_hide(){
    var morec = 0;
    $("li", list).each(function(index) {
        if (index >= limit) {
            $(this).hide();      
            morec = index - limit + 1;
        }
    });

    if (!more) more = morec;

    if (more) {
        list.append('<li class="more">' + more + ' more</li>');
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}


if (tricky_hide()) {
    list.live("mouseover", function() {
        $("li", list).each(function(index) {
            $(this).show();
        });
        $("li.more", list).hide();
    });

    list.live("mouseout", function() {
        tricky_hide();
    });
}
```

​It works perfectly but I need some clarifications.
I have this piece of function

```
if (more) {
            list.append('<li class="more">' + more + ' more</li>');
            return true;
        }
```

that appends the `<li class="more">` also on mouseout event. If i "mouseover" and "mouseout" on this element infinite times, it write in my html document infinite `<li class="more">`.
How to prevent this? How can I append only once (on page load, i.e.) this element?

Thanks to all!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MYM2C/

Comment: `more` is not a bool. It should be if you want clean code.

Comment: @Rune Look again. He's using `more` to store the index.

Comment: @Rune it's pretty common in JS to check non-bools for their truthy/falsyness.

Comment: @m90 Sure is, but I guess he was referring to using 1/0 in place of true/false, which is a bad practice. But in this case `more` is used to store an integer.

Comment: @m90 just as Marcus says, I was referring to the bad practice part. I always go for readability and clean code, it's a kind of OCD for me, so I always use bools and bools only for true/false checking. I think everybody should do it because it really helps increasing readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the solution should be as easy as:

```
li_element = list.find('li.more');
if (more && !li_element.length) {
    list.append('<li class="more">' + more + ' more</li>');
    return true;
} else {
    li_element.show();
}
```

Comment: Yep, this should do it. But seeing underscores in var names makes me a sad panda. Why not keep it consistent to native JS where more or less everything is camelCase or CamelCaps? :) (Edit: Yes, I know its a matter of personal preference)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall your comment is well received... I personally feel pain when I see code styling that's unreadable to me as well... however, as a PHP coder, I've got used to this convention and so I am using it in JavaScript as well... sorry to make you a sad panda though

Comment: I was guessing that's where it came from. Evil PHP! ;) In my own experience it has actually helped me keeping languages and syntaxes apart by following their own specs and style guides as closely as possible (dash-separation in css/html, camelCase/CamelCaps in JavaScript, underscore in PHP etc), but this does not not apply to everyone, obviously! It also has the added benefit of being easier to work with in larger projects with multiple developers, since nobody really can debate against it :)